# setSelected boolean cannot be apply to int

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner and I'd like to set the 30 as default:

```
String[] items = new String[]{"15", "30", "60", "90", "Off"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
    int spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition("30");
    dropdown.setSelected(spinnerPosition);
```

The problem is in the line `dropdown.setSelected(spinnerPosition);` the spinnerPosition is giving me the error: **setSelect (boolean) in View cannot be apply to (int)**

any ideas how to solve it and set 30 as default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use `setSelection()`, not set selected :)

And before this set adapter for your spinner / dropdown :)